# Changing posts date

Tags: php

Im trying to change the date of every post after a specific date to an older, back in another year. My code used to work just fine on PHP 5, but it doesnt on PHP 7. I was wondering what changes I should do. I know that some things are deprected on PHP 7, but im not sure about the parts I need to edit.

Here's my code. Thanks everyone in advance for helping.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "db";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM dm_posts where post_date > '2017-04-30'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Post Title</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["ID"]."</td><td>".$row["id"]." ".$row["post_title"]."</td></tr>" ;
$idd = $row["ID"];
$int= rand(1388534400,1418342400);
$futuredate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$int);
$query1 = "UPDATE dm_posts SET post_date = '".$futuredate."' where post_date > '2017-04-30' and id = '".$idd."'";
$result1 = $conn->query($query1);
    }
    echo "</table>";


} else {
    echo "All IS DONE";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Also why not doing this through WordPress API ?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use **post_date** field as UNIX Time stamp. Then you will use above code. May be you have update the date of post

Comment: post_date is set to a unix timestamp through $int= rand(1388534400,1418342400);

Comment: But you have converted UNIX time stamp to date format and you have also used in select  query post_date as date format. It should be in UNIX time stamp.

Comment: thats untrue. im still testing this script under php 5.6 and it works fine.

Comment: Please use mt_rand() instead of rand(). Try it may it will work.

Comment: This one didnt help at all.

Comment: What post_date field  in DB has to do with PHP 7 ? Also as of PHP 7.1.0, `rand()` uses the same random number generator as `mt_rand()`.

Comment: @Laxmana thats what im talking about. Its all about syntax.